# How can I get users last login date using Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Does Graph API provide any API to get users last login date? I currently work on list all users last login date, but I can't find any user's login information from Microsoft Graph documentation.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is no such API in Microsoft that provides this feature. If you were using the Azure AD premium, as a workaround, you can use the [reporting APIs’ signin Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-reporting-api-sign-in-activity-reference).

And you can vote the similar feedback from [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/18950242-msgraph-to-get-the-user-s-last-login-datetime-or) if you want to Microsoft to support this feature.

Comment: Please vote on the following if this feature is important to you:  https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/category/101632-microsoft-graph-o365-rest-apis?query=last%20login

Answer (score 0):

This is supported in Graph Beta only currently and it's the filed 'signInActivity' on the user. (See here for reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-beta)

To get it with graph api:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id | userPrincipalName}?$select=displayName,signInActivity
```